# Display the exact exposure date of an image

Tags: bash, terminal, exiftool

I have an image `IMG_01.PNG`

I can display the image exposure date by doing:
`exiftool -CreateDate IMG_01.JPG`
This prints:

```
Create Date                     : 2017:04:15 10:06:40
```

But I want to display this date in microsecond accuracy, for example if I do:
`stat -c %w IMG_01.JPG` I get:

```
2020-07-17 00:44:30.483242603 +0100
```

But this is not the date that I want. How can I display a more accurate date using exiftool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exiftool can only display info actually embedded in the file or properties of the file that are supported by the Perl libraries it uses.  In the case of the embedded `CreateDate`, that tag only allows for accuracy down to the seconds and all tags completely rely on whatever the source of the image actually embedded.  In case of the file system time stamp returned by stat, see [this post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11180.0) on the exiftool forums.

Comment: Thank you so much. This means that this info does not exist. Extra info: https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11437.0